# Converting a php loop to a simple MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, loops

sorry if this is a dumb question. And thanks for your time. I have searched around and found similar issues/answers - but have not found quite what I'm looking for.

I'm used to doing all my MySQL calls via PHP - but recently - I have been given a task for a very large database table with 5000 000 stockbroker records. The PHP I have works fine - but takes HOURS to complete. Thinking this will be much faster with simple MySQL calls... The "simple"-ness gets lost on me.

My_Table:

```
| ID | My_Stockbroker | My_Start_Date | My_End_Date | POST_SIZE |
| 1  |     DAVE       |  2000-06-19   | 2000-06-19  |     2     |
| 2  |     DAVE       |  1999-03-02   | 2002-09-06  |     0     |
| 3  |     DAVE       |  1999-03-14   | 2002-12-10  |     0     |
| 4  |     SAM        |  2000-06-19   | 2000-06-19  |           |
```

---

The target table for update is `My_Table` - I want to update all the `POST_SIZE' values on`My_Table`

---

My PHP is very straightforward:

- POST_SIZE is initially blank
- Get one single `My_Stockbroker` name from the My_Table = "DAVE"
- count any other records (not including the record being handled) from My_Table that = "DAVE" AND fall within a specific date range
  i.e.
  `My_Table`.`My_Start_Date` < "ID1".`My_Table`.`My_Start_Date`  && `My_Table`.`My_End_Date` > "ID1".`My_Table`.`My_Start_Date` POST_SIZE ++;

My PHP code is like this:

```
// Get 1 record
$sql = "SELECT `ID`, ` My_Stockbroker`,  `My_Start_Date`, from `".$Table."` WHERE ` My_Stockbroker` != '' AND `POST_SIZE` = '' LIMIT 1"; //

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){// while 1 record result
    $ My_Stockbroker_To_Examin_ID = $row["ID"];
    $ My_Stockbroker_To_Examin = $row[" My_Stockbroker"];
    $ My_Stockbroker_To_Examin_My_Start_Date = $row["My_Start_Date"];
}

/////// GET ALL RECORDS FOR SPECIFIC  My_Stockbroker that fall within specific date ///////
$sql = "SELECT `ID` FROM `".$Table."` WHERE `My_Start_Date` < 
'".$My_Stockbroker_To_Examin_My_Start_Date."' AND `My_End_Date` > 
'".$My_Stockbroker_To_Examin_My_Start_Date."' AND `My_Stockbroker` = 
'".$My_Stockbroker_To_Examin."' AND `ID` != '".$ My_Stockbroker_To_Examin_ID ."'"; // 

if($result = $conn->query($sql)){//
   $POST_SIZE = $result->num_rows;
}

// now write back the number of rows found    
$sql = "UPDATE `".$Table."` SET `POST_SIZE` = '".$POST_SIZE."', WHERE `ID` = '".$My_Stockbroker_To_Examin_ID."'; ";
```

---

As I said - the PHP code I have works flawlessly.
I just don't have time to wait hours for it to complete.

**How can this be achieved - on the one table - using just MySQL?**

**Read One Record / Count All records within date range / write value to `POST_SIZE`**

Do I need to create a bunch of temp tables on the fly, and joins etc.? 
Or can this be achieved in a MySQL loop?
Is MySQL typically faster Alone? - Or am I maybe going about it wrong with my PHP?

Comment: Is your table indexed?

Comment: I'm looking for a complete statement, that writes back to the `POST_SIZE` column for each row.

Comment: What are you doing a separate query for each stock broker? That's really a lot of queries and probably having a big impact.

Comment: Also is there a reason that you can't just subtract 1 rather than having that whole `NOT` clause?

Comment: Thanks Elin : )
I guess Im doing a separate query because I want to loop through the entire database - and when making the comparisons with the date - I want to exclude the record that is being examined - only the record that is being examined is updated, based on the other entries from that broker. Not sure if I am doing it right. It works great on a small scale. As I said - I have not worked with very large databases before and am trying to learn how to speed this process up - PHP or MySQL - It seems I need to loop the whole database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this sql, but it should be something like

```
UPDATE My_Table set Post_size = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM My_Table 
 WHERE ID <> My_Stockbroker_To_Examin_ID 
 AND My_Start_Date < My_Stockbroker_To_Examin_My_Start_Date 
 AND My_End_Date > My_Stockbroker_To_Examin_My_Start_Date 
 AND My_Stockbroker = My_Stockbroker_To_Examin)
```

You could replace these variables with the required values.

Comment: Do you know?... Is this typically supposed to be faster with MySQL - Or am I maybe going about it wrong with my PHP?

Comment: Fast depends on many many other criterias. For that I ll need your table structure and other things! We will have to see whether the right columns are indexed or not.

Comment: Thanks Neels. I guess I'm just asking - under optimal settings - for both PHP and MySQL. Is it reasonable to take hours to process 5000 000 records with PHP? Should this be a lot faster with MySQL? Whats the norm time length for processing like this with large databases? I guess Im asking because I have not worked with very large database tables before. So I am not sure what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this whole process in a single query statement like

```
SELECT `ID` 
FROM 
(
SELECT `ID` as MSID, 
`My_Stockbroker` as MSB,  
`My_Start_Date` as MSD
 from My_Table
 WHERE `My_Stockbroker` IS NOT NULL AND `POST_SIZE` IS NULL
 ORDER BY `ID` LIMIT 1
) tab
WHERE `My_Start_Date` < MSD
AND `My_End_Date` > MSD 
AND `My_Stockbroker` = MSB
AND `ID` != MSID;
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Does this write back to the same table?

Comment: @Kreeverp, NO, it's a select statement. If you meant to `UPDATE` as in your post .. you can include the result of select query to your UPDATE statement..

Comment: I was looking for a statement that also wrote back the results?

Comment: First get all the data (in one pass, not separate passes for each broker) and then do one update.